# InDesign — DIN 5008 downloadable (buyable) template?

Tags: adobe-indesign, template

The [DIN 5008](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DIN_5008):2011-04 seems to be quite popular in Germany for business letters but I cannot find any templates for InDesign. There are a lot of tutorials, but no ready to use solution.

[image]

I mean, it's not that hard to create a template like this and I will certainly do so, but maybe I was looking at the wrong places and there are ready to use solutions?

**Update:** Here is my [solution](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1psJZO31TNL9fdqVMHxow_Bemr3Z6OLDS/view?usp=sharing) (a fast one).

Comment: Sometimes it's just easier to build the template yourself! :) You've got a good guide there to follow. You will probably spend more time looking for a template than it will take to build it.

Comment: I don't speak German but was still able to find an INDD template in less than a minute.. "DIN 5008:2011-04 INDD Template" on Google.

Comment: To be frank, if all a template contains are measurements for position, I *prefer* to set it up myself to ensure the measurements are accurate. Not all templates are as accurate as they purport to be. You can be bitten by trusting a "measurement only" template.

Comment: @GoofyMonkey Seems to be true. I created one for myself.

Comment: @Scott Well, if there is a solution used by many people and organisations, the chances are high that it was checked and double-checked by some of them. But "trust nobody but yourself" strategy is not wrong at all :)

Comment: Yeah, you would think.. but well.. there's no telling if the template you download is correct just because the name presents itself as the same as the template you are looking for.

Comment: I can't tell you how many times I've had to use a template provided to me that was incorrect. Usually the answer I get back is something like "Yea, it was wrong before I got here and nobody wants to fix it"...